# Buscar y ordenar desde un espacio en una columna

Tags: mysql

Quiero hacer una vista donde busque por el apellido y ordenar por el mismo, el nombre y apellido están juntos (en esta ocación se desea que así permanezcan), he estado probando usando *like* pero no encuentro la forma de lograr lo que deseo.
Esto es parte de lo que tengo, estoy buscando los actores que tengan un **son** en el apellido.
De antemano muchas gracias.

```sql
select distinct actores From peliculas 
    where actores Like '%________son%' order by actores asc
    ;
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, para poder ayudarte es necesario que nos des un [Ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que tienes, ademas, ¿por que no te pasas por [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)? luego puedes editar y mejorar tu pregunta, un saludo :D

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ¿el `son` debe estar exactamente al final de la cadena? en ese caso prueba con un **like** cómo: `LIKE '%son'`

Comment: @Josbert Gracias

Comment: Si necesitas que haya un espacio exactamente antes de la palabra `son` entonces prueba con `LIKE '% son'` si eso no te funciona, puedes usar **regex**

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intentaré